# How to determine if fragment at top of other fragment is removed

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have fragment A and **adding** fragment B in same container (**not replacing**). I am adding this transaction on backstack also. Now, when device back is pressed, fragment B will be removed and fragment A will become visible. I want to do something when fragment A becomes visible. I searched lot but could not find anything helpful.

Note - I don't want to add backstackchangelistner and call onResume on that fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden)` in a Fragment.
This will be called when its shown/hidden.

I use the same approach in my app, where i add a fragment and hide the old one, and then use the onHiddenChanged callback when the user presses Back, and the old fragment is shown again.

Comment: As I said, I have added fragment and not replaced. I think, onHiddenChaged is called when replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
As you have 2 entries in Back stack, you can check back stack count on 
Back Pressed method.
FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
      int count=  mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        if(count==1){
            // do your work
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
@Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
    }
```

or

```
 `fragment.isVisible();`
```